# Side effect of dielectric polarization

Tags: polarity, dielectric

Sorry for my  obvious  question, but  I am not from the field of electronics and electric  engineering.

I was reading [this article](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0022-3727/47/45/455302/meta): 
The first sentence in the introduction says: " *All solid dielectrics exhibit the propensity to accumulate electrical charges under electrical stress beyond an electric field threshold.* "

First question, is dielectric polarization the same as saying dielectric accumulate electric charges ?

I would like also  to  ask about the diadvantages of  accumulation of  electric charges in dielectrics, can some one give a me a real example from daily life problems?

I read somewhere that   this can cause cables to be damaged, how this occurs?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are mixing concepts such as polarised Capacitor with dielectric. 
1) I would recomend you to read WIKI: [Dielectric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric)

But basicly dielectric polarization is the distribution of charges in a dielectric material (aislator). Not all aislator materials are dielectric materials. Usually these material are used to reduce the Electric field, like in capacitors.

2) The capacitance on another hand in a capacitor filled with dielectric is explained here: [Capacitance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance)

3, 4) A good examples are wires with high tension. If you try to touch it without special protection it can kill you. Also normal wires also have capacitance and it can be different in different conditions. For example in an HDMI cable the signal may lose it's matching and this will make impossible to see correctly the image.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, however I am really confused about the expression " dielectric accumulate  electric charges under electric field" what does this mean ?

Comment: Ok, I think now I understand you question about accumulate electric acharges. What it means is that without electric field you wont have any charge. Also there is a relationship between the separation and the electric field. This article explains it in more details [link](http://www.capacitorguide.com/electric-field/). I won't be able to explain it in more details, as it's basicly a whole chapter in a book "physics for engineers and scientists". What it expalins is the relationship between, the dielectric, the structure of capacitor and the behaviour of electric field and charges.

Comment: Thank you again for your time explaing this concept. However I edited my question to  make it more precise.

Comment: ok. I will check it later and try to answer it all.